# Using String Buffer For String Appends in Java

Tags: java, string, append, sonarqube, stringbuffer

I would like to know if this use of StringBuffer does the same thing as my previous code, because SonarQube asks me not to use `+=` for appending strings.

My previous code :

```
String sign = "";
if (value < 0) {
    sign.append("-");
}
```

My new code with StringBuffer :

```
StringBuffer sign = new StringBuffer();
sign.append("");
if (value < 0) {
    sign.append("-");
}
```

Is this better this way ?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Third way: `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Should I use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` ? Sonar recommends the second one by the way.

Comment: Wait, what? Since when did Sonar recommend the use of StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder?

Comment: Rather use `StringBuilder`, this gives you more functionality they just `String` and since `StringBuffer` is designed to be thread safe, it will perform a lot worse than `StringBuilder` (not thread safe)

Comment: Well, one produces a compile time error, the other works. (There is no `append` method in the `String` class). Also it wouldn't work that way, since strings are immutable (e.g. if you use `concat`, a new string is returned).

Comment: `sign.append("");` does nothing

Comment: @Tunaki Sonar Qube failed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using that code in a loop, there no bad in your first way (*String concatination*). For a single attempt you can use that.

As someone commented I assume by writing `sign.append("-");`, you mean `sign +="-"`

If you are using in a loop I suggest to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` since there is another overhead with `StringBuffer` is it is synchronized. Unless you need Thread safety, better to change it to `StringBuilder`.

I'm not sure why SonarQube suggest you to use `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer` is better approach that `String` Concatenation.

Because It will give better memory utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's better way, but `StringBuffer` is slower than `StringBuilder`, but synchronized.

If you are using this code is not in a multithreaded application I recommend you use `StringBuilder`.